# How do I get a keyset of double arrays (e.g. array[double]) from a LinkedHashMap set

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, double

I have been tackling the travelling salesperson problem for a final year module. I have been using LinkedHashMaps to store different journeys as array[double] keys so that I could pair the journeys with their journey length values.

I am using the line of code below to try and get the keys:

```
List<Double> keyList = new ArrayList<Double>(hmap.keySet());
```

But it isn't working and keeps throwing an error (`Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.Set<double[]>)'`.

How do you get a key set from a LinkedHashMap set when the keys are double[] types?

Comment: You shouldn't use arrays as a map key.

Comment: Why? Also, how would you represent a 4 point/digit tour in a hashMap as a key?

Comment: Arrays don't have value equality. That is, `!arr.equals(arr.clone())`. Either create a custom class with a proper `equals()` implementation or use a collection type, like `List`.

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't make an `ArrayList` of `Double` by passing the constructor a `Set` of `double[]`. `Double` is an object representing one floating point number. `double[]` is an **array** of native datatypes, each one representing one floating point number.

Comment: So I'd have to convert/change the value to already be an arraylist of doubles instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types for hmap? You can't create a List or Set of native types such as int and double.  You would have to use classes like Integer or Double instead.  If that isn't possible, you can create an empty keyList and loop through your keySet and add each key like this: `keyList.add(Double.valueOf(hmap.keySet()[i])`